# What is the way to display modal with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

What is the reason that I can't display the modal when I use `useEffect` ?
what's wrong in my code and how can I fix it to display the modal as I want in my example ?
In my example I just have `noItemsModal()` function that I want it work in the case of the `useEffect` below .

```
function tabol({ paramsList = { list: [] } }) {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

 function noItemsModal() {
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>

            <TouchableHighlight
              style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: '#2196F3' }}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>;
setModalVisible(true);
  }

  ////////

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataList == 0) {
      noItemsModal();
    }
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: uhmmm, there is so much wrong here, I seriously recommend that you start reading the reactjs.org documentation

Comment: can u help me please ?

Comment: Can you then format the code like you are using it right now? There is a function in a function, you don't return the jsx, you call setModalVisible underneath the jsx and the useEffect is missing dataList in dependency array

Comment: for a start, you're calling `noItemsModal`... but its returned value isn't being used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're new in React Native :) First of all, your  component needs to stay in the main return function. All you need to do is, change the `modalVisible` state. It will appear and disappear itself. You should not call the WHOLE  component itself. It should stay in the main return or render function and only modalVisible state will re-render itself.

Here is the basic example:

https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-modal-example

### To Run

- `npm i`
- `react-native run-ios/android`

Comment: I can create a basic example for you

Comment: I've added the basic example. Simply run `npm i` and `react-native run-ios/android` and it should work. 
Also, I think you need to work on basic React usage. In your example code; you're missing some important issues on React.

Comment: why i wrong when i try call the function inside useffect ?

Comment: You try to call whole component in the function and it has setModalVisible. It is unlogical

Comment: Just examine my example, you will understand :)

Comment: i stuck, do u have email or facebook that i can contact with u ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you're haveing is that all components need to return JSX, the useEffect it's just for effect functions, not for render JSX.
So in this case you just need to modify de `modalVisible` state from the useEffect callback and always return the modal JSX, wich renders itself based on the `visible`prop.

```
function tabol({ paramsList = { list: [] } }) {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const noItemsModal = React.useCallback(() => 
    setModalVisible(true)
    ,[setModalVisible]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    list === 0 && noItemsModal(true);
  }, [list]);

  return <View style={styles.centeredView}>
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.centeredView}>
        <View style={styles.modalView}>
          <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: '#2196F3' }}
            onPress={() => {
              setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  </View>;
}
```